# Gridview time format

Tags: asp.net

I have a BoundField that's using a Datafield linked to a datetime type variable. I want to display only the time, not the date. How do you show the time in 24-hour format or in AM/PM format, depending on a boolean in the code behind.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<%# Eval("AmPmMode").ToString().Equals("true")) ? 
String.Format("{0:hh}:{0:mm} {tt}", Eval("date")) : 
String.Format("{0:HH}:{0:mm}", Eval("date"))  %>
```

You can format your date for AM PM mode or for 24h mode. tt is the AM/PM designator.
AmPmMode is flag from you DB, should be true or false, but you could change it to 0 or 1.

See also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Just to clarify, AmPmMode would have to be a property of the object being bound to the grid, right?

Comment: In my case it would be part of the Datasource, if it's a property, you don't need the Eval() part.